# React custom event

Tags: reactjs

In react what is the best way to create a custom event?

As an example instead of:

```
handleKeyPress: function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        doSomething();
    }
}
...
<input onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
```

It would be nice to do be able to just do:

```
<input onEnter={doSomething} />
```

Is this possible?

I could create a custom wrapper for `<input>` but then what if I wanted to add it to `<select>` or `<textarea>`?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a base component that could handle all your possible events and extends that component to create custom elements, I'll say is easier this way because you will have available all your events in one class in case you need to add more or change some behaviors.

```js
class BaseElement extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
    this.onEnter = this.onEnter.bind(this);
    this.onSpace = this.onSpace.bind(this);
    this.onKeyPress = this.onKeyPress.bind(this);
  }
  onEnter (e) {
    this.props.onEnter()
  }
  onSpace (e) {
    this.props.onSpace()
  }
  onKeyPress (e) {
    switch(e.key){
      case 'Enter':
        this.onEnter()
      break;
      case ' ':
        this.onSpace()
      break;
      default:
        this.props.onChange()
      break;
    }
  }
};

class CustomText extends BaseElement {
  render() {
    return (
      <input type='text' onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress} />
    )
  }
};


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
     return (
         <CustomText onSpace={e => console.log('space')}
         onEnter={e => console.log('Enter')} />
     )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='app'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea. Unfortunately its does end up being quite long especially if I want to do the same to `<select>` `<textarea>` etc so I don't know if it's worth it. It might not be possible to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add `onEnter` or any other custom prop to standard dom elements. You can, however, wrap them in custom React components:

```
const MyInput = ({onEnter}) => (
    <input onKeyPress={e => e.key === 'Enter' ? onEnter(e) : null } />
);

....

<MyInput onEnter={doSomething} />
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just write a utility wrapper that takes the action as a parameter and returns the handler function:

```
function onEnter(action) {
    return function(e) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

and then import it and use it on whichever element I desired

```
<input onKeyPress={onEnter(doSomething)} />
```